# Output to UITextField

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, textbox

I have a `NSDictionary` with some parameters i want to display in a `UITextField`.
but

```
firstname.text = [userdata objectForKey:@"firstname"];
```

throws an exeption.
If i use `NSLog` on `[userdata objectForKey:@"firstname"];` it shows the right value. What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: This is the thrown exception: 2012-07-05 15:55:56.533 Project[13642:f803] -[__NSArrayM _isNaturallyRTL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68c4e20
2012-07-05 15:55:56.534 Project[13642:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM _isNaturallyRTL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68c4e20'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the following code:

```
firstname.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                   [userdata objectForKey:@"firstname"]];
```

go on .. :)

Comment: this works but it puts the values in brackets. the text box shows "(  firstname)" instead of "firstname"

Answer (score 2):

When you `NSLog` something it uses `[object description]` to convert the object to a string for output. If the object stored in your dictionary is not an NSString and you try to assign to `firstname.text` you will get an exception.

Another problem you may be facing is your `firstname` object may not be pointing at what you think it is. This may occur, for example, if you are not using ARC and you forgot to retain it or you already released it.

The exact exception you are seeing will determine which of these you are encountering.

Comment: This is the thrown exception: 2012-07-05 15:55:56.533 Project[13642:f803] -[__NSArrayM _isNaturallyRTL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68c4e20 2012-07-05 15:55:56.534 Project[13642:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM _isNaturallyRTL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68c4e20'

Comment: So the object stored in your dictionary is an NSArray not a NSString. Look at where you set the contents of that key and your bug should be there1

Comment: So the object in the `firstname` key is an `NSArray` not an `NSString`. Check where you set the value for that key!

Answer (score 1):

Tried to do something like

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[userdata objectForKey:@"firstname"]];
firstname.text = nameString;
```

?

Comment: That would need to be `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[userdata objectForKey:@"firstname"]];` otherwise, if the object is not an NSString* it will throw an exception. Adding the @"%@" causes stringWithFormat to invoke the `-[NSObject description]` method on the object to produce a string representation. (Of course, in the rare case that the object is not a descendent of `NSObject` and does not implement a `description` method it could still fail).

Comment: No worries, have made the same mistake myself ;-)